# Google ad manager try to read revenue per hour fails on ReportError.COLUMNS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REQUESTED_DIMENSIONS

Tags: ruby, google-ad-manager

I have a simple script that fetch data from google ad manager. 
Everything is working pretty fine, Now I am trying to read the same data but instead of date aggregation, I am trying by day and hour.

I get the following error:

```
AdManagerApi::V201905::ReportService::ApiException: [ReportError.COLUMNS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REQUESTED_DIMENSIONS @ columns; trigger:'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE']
```

My report query in ruby is:

```
# Create report query.
report_query = {
  :date_range_type => 'CUSTOM_DATE',
  :start_date => AdManagerApi::AdManagerDate.new(@ad_manager, start_date).to_h,
  :end_date => AdManagerApi::AdManagerDate.new(@ad_manager, end_date).to_h,
  :dimensions => ['DAY', 'HOUR', 'CUSTOM_CRITERIA'],
  :columns => ['TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE']

}
```

I took the full example from [here](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/tree/master/ad_manager_api/examples/v201905/report_service)

I am pretty new with the google ad manager api, I will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `CUSTOM_CRITERIA` from the `:dimensions` list